# как вывести ассоц массива, в 3 разнх дивах, по очереди, по одной строке в каждом

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?
 $ctalog = [];
 while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() )
   $catalog[] = $row;
?>

<!--
  Мне нужно вывести массив $catalog в foreach'е, 
  и как то сделать вывод в первый ряд, второй ряд, треттий ряд 
  Что бы каждая строка массива по  очереди в каждый ряд 1,2,3 попадала.
  В итоге все глядит в линию по вертикали, красиво, как тут 
  http://www.bootply.com/render/90113
-->
<!--первый ряд-->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
...$catalog[0]['title'] итерация 1
...$catalog[3]['title'] итерация 2
</div>
<!--второй ряд-->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
...$catalog[1]['title'] итерация 1
...$catalog[4]['title'] итерация 2
</div>
<!--третий ряд-->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
...$catalog[2]['title'] итерация 1
...$catalog[5]['title'] итерация 2
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите свой воспрос в порядок и на данном сайте стоит использовать русский язык. Не понятно зачем первая ссылка стоит

Comment: Готово. я отредактровала подскажите пож как мне решить вопрос

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Цикл **foreach** не подходит для этой задачи. Вот решение с помощью цикла **for**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
for ($i=0;$i<count($catalog);$i+=3){
    if ($catalog[$i]){
        echo $catalog[$i]['title'];   
    }
}
</div>
<!--второй ряд-->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
for ($i=1;$i<count($catalog);$i+=3){
    if ($catalog[$i]){
        echo $catalog[$i]['title'];
    }
}
</div>
<!--третий ряд-->
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
for ($i=2;$i<count($catalog);$i+=3){
    if ($catalog[$i]){
        echo $catalog[$i]['title'];
    }
}
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо очень круто).

Comment: @МансурШайхаев чего крутого `if ($catalog[$i]){` warning undefiened index обеспечен сразу. if(isset($catalog[$i])) как миниму нужен.

Comment: В каком случае такая ошибка в сгенерируется? у меня все норм.